# node.js - how to pass additional parameters to async.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

**Background Information**

I'm trying to write some javascript / node.js code that will do the following:

1. Query a redis database and get back a bunch of keys from my hash.  This is what the command looks like on the redis-cli:

   127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys widgets:1231231234
   1) "13:00:00_17:00:00_mtwrf"
   2) "00:00:00_00:00:00"
   3) "08:00:00_12:00:00_mtwrf"

or 
    127.0.0.1:6379> hkeys widgets:2222222222
    1) "00:00:00_00:00:00"

Each widget will have at least one key... called the default key.  Default keys look like this: "00:00:00_00:00:00"

For each HKEYS query, if there's more than one result returned, I need to test each key returned (except the default) against a set of match criteria.  Whichever key matches, is what is used to do a subsequent HGET against redis.  So for example, in the first result set shown above... If key 3 was a match I would run the following command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hget widgets:2222222222 08:00:00_12:00:00_mtwrf
"some value"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

If neither key 1 or 3 matches, then I query for the default key.

**Code**

I've recently discovered the async module. I'm currently using it in my code to loop through the results from HKEYS.
Please see the code below:

**async.map Code**

```
router.get('/:widgetnum', function(req, res, next) {
  //validate widgetnum format        
  var widgetnum = req.params.widgetnum;
  if ( !valid_widget(widgetnum) ) {
      var retval = {"res":false, "msg":"malformed widgetnum"};
      res.send(JSON.stringify(retval));
 } else {
      var keys = {};
      redis.hkeys("widgets:" + widgetnum, function(err, data){
          if (err) {
              res.send(JSON.stringify(false));
          }
          if (data) {
             current = getCurrentUTC(); // needed by iterator for match criteria. Using a global variable for now.                                 
            async.map(data, hash_iterator, function (err, iterator_results) {
                  if (iterator_results) {
                      console.log("it are: " + iterator_results);
                  }
                  res.send(iterator_results);
             }); //end async map
          }

      }); //end redis.hkeys
  }
});
```

**Question / Problem**

This is working in the sense that for each key returned by HKEYS, I'm able to run the "hash_iterator" function.

However, once inside the iterator function, after evaluation / running my match criteria on each result, I don't have all the information I need to run the secondary HGET query.

The code:

```
  async.map(data, hash_iterator, function (err, iterator_results)
```

passes just the values:

```
 "13:00:00_17:00:00_mtwrf"
  "00:00:00_00:00:00"
  "08:00:00_12:00:00_mtwrf"
```

But I need the hash name (in this case "widgets:" ) and the widgetnum to make the HGET call.

I guess I can use global variables... but I wanted to make sure that my approach in general is correct here.

Any input would be appreciated.

Here's the hash_iterator logic:

```
var hash_iterator = function (redis_key, doneCallBack) {
        var results = {};
        console.log("processing..." + redis_key);
        //skip if default rule....
        if (redis_key.indexOf('00:00:00_00:00:00') == -1){
                //need to write logic here to do HGET and save 
                //results somewhere... in case no other keys match 

        } else {
               // run some logic to test match criteria.
              if (matchfound) {
                        console.log("bingo.  found match in " +  redis_key);
                        redis.hget(hashname + widgetnum + redis_key, function (e, results){
                          if (results) {
                                return doneCallBack(null, results);
                          } else {
                                 return doneCallBack(null, null);
                          }

                       });                           

                }else {
                        console.log ("no match");
                }
        } 
        return results;
}
```

Comment: I guess you'll want to look into closures. Just define that `hash_iterator` function in scope that has access the variable containing your `"widgets:"` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it in functional style with map. Just generate array of pairs and then pass it to `async.map`, for example
from `[1,2,3]` you can generate `[['key', '1'], ['key', '2'], ['key', 3]]`

So here the code, that generating pairs:

```
redis.hkeys("widgets:" + widgetnum, function(err, data){
    // some code goes here

    var pairs = data.map(function(ts) {
      return [`widgets:${widgetnum}`, ts];
    });

    // async.map call goes here
}); //end redis.hkey
```

Inside `async.map` iterator callback you can access key with `iterator_results[0]`

**But** in your case the variable `widgetnums` **is not global variable**. It's just variable from upper scope and you can use it inside nested functions if you define it in propper scope. It's very useful trick that called [lexical closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: sorry, i don't quite understand this code sample. I think I understand your opening sentence about trying to pass the key to async.map but I don't understand what data.map is.  Can you add some context to this code to make it clearer?

Comment: I added context to my answer